# Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManagerInterface

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I am upgrading Magento to version 2.4.2. After upgraded, when I ran di compile command,

I got the below error.

```
Errors during compilation:
    WeltPixel\ThankYouPage\Controller\Newsletter\Subscribe
        Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManagerInterface. Actual type: array; File: 
/var/www/html/module/app/code/WeltPixel/ThankYouPage/Controller/Newsletter/Subscribe.php
```

I checked the Subscribe.php file but I didn't get anything.

Subscribe.php

```
<?php
namespace WeltPixel\ThankYouPage\Controller\Newsletter;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface as CustomerAccountManagement;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Subscribe extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerUrl
     * @param CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
         parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $subscriberFactory,
            $customerSession,
            $storeManager,
            $customerUrl,
            $customerAccountManagement,
            $data
        );
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
       
    }


    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateEmailAvailable($email)
    {
        /**
         * Original function rewritten
         * Allow the subscription for user on checkout success page for the same email address
         */
        $orderEmail = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
        if ($orderEmail == $email) {
            return true;
        }
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        if ($this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() !== $email
            && !$this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($email, $websiteId)
        ) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('This email address is already assigned to another user.')
            );
        }
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
           return parent::execute();
        }


        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {

            $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
            $sucessMessage = '';

            try {
                $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

                $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
                if ($subscriber->getId()
                    && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
                ) {
                    return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(
                        [
                            'errors' => true,
                            'message' => __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                        ]
                    );
                }

                $status = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
                if ($status == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    $sucessMessage = __('The confirmation request has been sent.');
                } else {
                    $sucessMessage = __('Thank you for your subscription.');
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(
                    [
                        'errors' => true,
                        'message' => __('There was a problem with the subscription: %1', $e->getMessage())
                    ]
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(
                    [
                        'errors' => true,
                        'message' => __('Something went wrong with the subscription.')
                    ]
                );
            }

            return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(
                [
                    'errors' => false,
                    'message' => $sucessMessage
                ]
            );
        }

    }

}
```

if anyone knows, please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `WeltPixel\ThankYouPage\Controller\Newsletter\Subscribe` is an extend of `Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction` which was changed in 2.4.2 with an additional parameter SubscriptionManagerInterface (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/47e3ada764fc943fc63d88671ce10b2877fe57d0#diff-244d4c9eb135a719f51ad6ac8521bd91d4582a6c33e3a5b78c1b05b04b5bfcc3)

So `WeltPixel\ThankYouPage\Controller\Newsletter\Subscribe` will need to be updated with this parameter as well.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    Session $customerSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
    CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManagerInterface $subscriptionManager,
    JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
     parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $subscriberFactory,
        $customerSession,
        $storeManager,
        $customerUrl,
        $customerAccountManagement,
        $subscriptionManager,
        $data
    );
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
   
}
```

But all-in-all I think you're better off looking for an extension update from the developer. As there might be more 2.4.2 compatibility issues with the extension.